# Handling POST API next.js and architecture

Tags: next.js

I'm building my first next js app, my structure is;

- React - Frontend
- Next.js - Backend, but really just a collection of APIs
- MongoDB - Doc datastore

The frontend is working great, and is POSTing form data to the API I've specified. The problem I have is how do I handle the POST data in my API?

My code below handles querystring calls, but not POST calls. I've yet to add the req.method to determine which has been called, as I need the API to allow for querystring and form post data to be handled.

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../util/mongodb";
export default async function (req, res) {

    try {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
    const collection = db.collection("answers");
    const doc = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(req.url).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')
    const result = await collection.insertOne(doc);
    } finally {
       await  db.close();
    }
};
```

I've read a lot about using Express middleware, which seems to me to be overkill in a simple application I'm building (though I appreciate why a React JS app needs Express).

I followed the Next.js reference documentation, it has a //Handle POST data here, but no actual example.

So I'm now questioning if I've taken the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

So in regards to the problem, I spent days looking for the solution and the vast majority of tutorials handling routing skip over the actual handling of the POST itself. And the key element thats not called out straight in the documentation is `req.body`.

Here is my solution;

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../util/mongodb";
import questions from "./questions";
export default async function (req, res) {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
    try {
        const questions = await db
        const collection = questions.collection("answers");
        const doc = req.body;
        const result = await collection.insertOne(doc);
    } finally {
        res.end()
    }
};
```

It's lacking a check on the method, which is next, but thats straight forward, the handling of the POST is a bigger challenge even though incredibly simple to handle its not obvious elsewhere, so hope this helps.

If the above doesn't work, I'd realised I was posting over the form header with JSON specified, which won't work. You can also wrap req.body in JSON.stringify if needed.